# Tree-View Seeing all the directories e.g. on "C:/"

Tags: java, eclipse, tree, wicket, root

I have a problem concerning my tree-view. I try to create a tree to display my C:/- Drive. In "FooUtil", i already begun to create new Foos, by loading all Files into a Collection (via `file.listFiles()`). Then I run through the `Collection` and for each file I create a `new Foo`, with the parent "root" and the `fileName`. Now my question is do you guys could create a algorithm to read out all the files (and their sub-directories!!)? This is my code right now:

```
    File[] fileCollection = null;

    String[] list = fileFolder.list();
    fileCollection = fileFolder.listFiles();

    ArrayList<File> tempfileList = null;
    ArrayList<File> fileList = null;

    if (fileCollection != null) {
        fileList = Lists.newArrayList(fileCollection);
    } else {
        fileList = Lists.newArrayList();
    }

    final IModel<List<File>> fileListModel = new ListModel<File>(fileList);
    //

    Foo[] fooz = new Foo[fileList.size()];
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    // creating root
    Foo fooRoot = new Foo("root");
    // fooz[0] = new Foo("root");

    for (File file : fileListModel.getObject()) {
        // creating sub-directories in C:/
        fooz[i] = new Foo(fooRoot, file.getName());

        File tempFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
        //
        if (tempFile.listFiles() != null) {
            tempFileCollection = tempFile.listFiles();
            tempfileList = Lists.newArrayList(tempFileCollection);
            Foo[] fooz2 = new Foo[tempfileList.size()];
            x = 0;

            for (File file2 : tempFileCollection) {
                fooz2[x] = new Foo(fooz[i], file2.getName());

             // here i could go for the next subdirectories

                x++;
            }

        }
        //
        i++;
    }
    foosy.add(fooRoot);
    return foosy;
```

Comment: Either recursively - write a function that builds the tree for a given folder, and calls back into itself for each new folder it discovers - or build a queue of folders to search; work through the queue and every time you find a new folder add it to the back of the queue. There are probably more ways. In both case your state needs to be the folder name and the node you're adding it to.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wrote a function which returns a Foo that's added to the List<Foo> foosy. Do you think its better if i do it like this (adding the constructed Foo before the tree is being clicked) or would you say i should only add the Foos when a directorie in the tree is being clicked?